# How to execute large sql query in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, database

I want to store huge content in db and my sample text is 16129 characters in length when i tried to execute this query it is showing "error:The requested URL could not be retrieved" in firefox and "no-data received" in chrome.

I use `LONGTEXT` as datatype for column `content` in DB.

I also tried to execute the query directly in phpmyadmin with same huge content.It is working correctly.

The code is shown below.

```
    public function _getConnection($type = 'core_write') {
            return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
        }

    public function testdbAction(){
            $db = $this->_getConnection();
            $current_time=now();
            $text="The European languages are members of the same family......  ...Europe uses the same vocabulary. The ";
//$text is 16129 characters in length
            $sql = "INSERT into test(`usercontent_id`,`app_id`,`module_id`,`customer_id`,`content`,`created_time`,`updated_time`,`item_id`,`index_id`,`position_id`) VALUES (NULL, 15, 9,2,'" .$text. "','" . $current_time . "','" . $current_time . "',1003,5,4)";
           //echo  $sql; exit;
            $db->query($sql);        
        }
```

But when I tried the same in Magento,  `$db->query($sql);`  does not able to run the query. Kindly advice on this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Looking at the above it doesn't follow good Magento development practice - you should never have to execute a query with raw SQL so I would suggest there is certainly going to be a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @JonathanHussey Thanks, Yes i did not follow Mage::getModel to save it. When i tried with above code, It should work with query.But it does not...Kindly advice on this

Comment: You are going to have to give more detail than you have here for anyone to be able to diagnose the problem, for instance errors messages generated when running the query() method.

Comment: Try using `$db->exec($sql)` it executes the query and returns the amount of affected rows. Not sure if this will make a difference for you.

Comment: @RickKuipers Thanks it works. You saved me.

Comment: @Dinesh np, I added it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$db->exec($sql)` it executes the query and returns the amount of affected rows.
I think `$db->query()` only gets executed when fetch is called as well...