# How do I get the MySQL (updated) affected rows when using the Magento resource?

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, sql

I am using following update query,

```
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$query = UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` val SET val.value = '11' 
WHERE val.attribute_id = 75 AND 
val.entity_id = (select cv.entity_id from `catalog_product_entity` as cv where cv.sku = '25' limit 1)

$afected = $db->query($query);
```

How could I get the affected rows count from the above query?. I have already looked on the
[How do I get the MySQL affected rows using the Magento resource?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10623/how-do-i-get-the-mysql-affected-rows-using-the-magento-resource) - but those not works for me.

Kindly advice me on the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `$db->exec($query);` instead of `$db->query($query);`. It returns the number of affected rows.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2905/how-to-execute-large-sql-query-in-magento

Comment: There is no `exec()` method in `Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface` on my Magento 1.9.4.1 installation. Not sure if 1.7 had it?

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find a lot of documentation on this, but this worked for me (Magento EE 1.10.1.1).

```
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$query = "UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` val SET val.value = '11' 
WHERE val.attribute_id = 75 AND 
val.entity_id = (select cv.entity_id from `catalog_product_entity` as cv where cv.sku = '25' limit 1)";

$result = $db->query($query);

// Get count of affected rows
$affected_rows = $result->rowCount();
```